# Mvc Using Ajax?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax

Which MVC version should I download to use the Ajax functionality in my MVC application? Is it possible with MVC 1.0?

I also want to use Modal Popups in my application.

Thanks
Ritz

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the **NerdDinner Tutorial.**  The part that talks about Ajax is here:
http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Part11.htm.

The NerdDinner Tutorial is written around **ASP.NET MVC 1.0.**

For the Modal Popups. I suggest using a jQuery plugin, like this one:
http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/

Answer (score 0):

here is example for you

```
function someJSFunction() {

    var request = new Sys.Net.WebRequest();
    var someID= (document.getElementById('DOMElementID').value);
    if (someID!= ""){
        var toControler = "/SomeControler/SoomeMethod/" + someID;
        request.set_url(toControler);
        request.set_httpVerb("GET");
        request.add_completed(someOtherJSFunction);
        request.invoke();
    }    
}
```